# Using Nokogiri to replace HTML placeholder tags

Tags: ruby-on-rails, templates, html-parsing, nokogiri

My particular use case is building HTML email templates that have placeholder values that are later replaced with real data.

Example:

```
hello <span class='placeholder' data-slug='contact.name'>contact.name</span>
```

...becomes "Hello John" when the placeholders are replaced.

I have 50+ of these placeholders, and am using Nokogiri to replace the placeholders with live data:

```
placeholder_mappings = {
  "contact.name" => @contact.name,
  "contact.email" => @contact.email,
  ...
}

text = "hello <span class='placeholder' data-slug='contact.name'>contact.name</span>"

page = Nokogiri::HTML(text)

placeholder_mappings.each do |key, value|
  page.css("[data-slug='#{key}']").each do |node|
    node.replace(value)
  end
end

page.to_html
```

The reason I'm using HTML tags instead of something like `{{contact.first_name}}` is so I can add CSS to the placeholders so users can easily see them when they are building the templates.  Otherwise, I would have just used a `gsub` and made it easy :)

The code I have above works, but it seems inefficient.  I've looked at the Nokogiri docs, but I confess node parsing is very new to me, and it will take me some time to get up-to-speed on the terminology.

Is there a more performant way to implement this, or is there an even better solution to my issue that I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some input based on your approach. You can make some improvement by not iterating through the hash `placeholder_mappings`, and instead fetching the value based on the key:

```
  page.css('span.placeholder').each do |node|
    node.replace(@placeholder_mappings[node['data-slug']])
  end
```

or use at_css

```
  node = page.at_css('span.placeholder')
  node.replace(@placeholder_mappings[node['data-slug']])
```

Seems your current approach is to process each placeholder separately. It might be faster to run the whole template through in one go:

```
  nodes = page.css('span.placeholder')
  nodes.each do |node|
    node.content = @placeholder_mappings[node['data-slug']]
  end
  nodes.remove_class("placeholder")
```

Here I'm not replacing the whole node as this makes iteration difficult. Instead I just replace the content and then remove `.placeholder` at the end to remove the CSS.

Comment: I can't believe I didn't think about only referencing the used mappings!  That should be much more performant, because most templates will only use 10 or so different placeholders.  With regards to not removing the nodes, the issue is that if I leave the `span` tag around and only remove the `class`, is that email clients print out the raw string `hello <span></span>` in subject lines.